# load .mat file - run out of memory

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix cube which I load in my program to read data from. The size of this .mat file is 2.8 GB. I am not being able to load it with the error of 'running out of memory'. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the data exceeds the available memory on your machine, then you are in trouble - this is unavoidable. However, if you only want certain variables inside the .mat file you can try to load just those variables using the

```
  load(filename, variables)
```

version of the load function. It really depends on the contents of your .mat file. If the file is 2.8GB and you need ALL of the variables in the file and your machine does not have enough memory to cope, your only option is to buy more RAM.

**EDIT** Apparently this answer is incorrect if you are running R2011b and above as explained in the answer of **Ben Voight**

Comment: Nice authoritative-sounding answer.  Unfortunately, it's also incorrect for current versions of MatLab.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair enough - I have an older version where this is not the case. Lets hope he has the OP has your version and not mine.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have edited my answer to point to yours for more recent versions

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `matfile` class to work on ranges within variables inside MatLab files.  See

- [Load and save parts of variables in MAT-files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matfile.html)

[Here's some additional discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9208) that discloses that this feature is new with R2011b.